# How to parameterise the sum of two closed rectifiable curves

Tags: complex-analysis

$γ : [0, 1] → C$ then $−γ = γ^{
−1}$
is defined as γ(1−t).

If also $σ : [0, 1] → C$
and $γ(1) = σ(0)$ then

γ + σ : [0, 1] → C is defined as
$$γ + σ =
\begin{cases}
γ(2t), &t ∈ [0, 1/2]\\
σ(2t − 1), &t ∈ [1/2, 1]
\end{cases}$$
This is written in Conway's book of complex analysis, and is used for proving the additivity of winding numbers. But how does this parameterisation comes. Isnt these two entire different curves which agree upon just the initial points. Ps: i don't know differential geometry.( advanced)So explanation within the scope of complex analysis would be really good . I have an idea of homotpy stuffs

Comment: What does     mean?

Comment: I have attempted to improve your text. Please edit it in order to learn a little how one can write formulas in Latex.

Comment: Can somebody hint?

Comment: I don't see the problem. If the path $\gamma$ connect the point $x$ to $y$, and $\sigma$ connect $y$ to $z$, then $\gamma+\sigma$ is the path that connect $x$ to $z$ by first "travelling" through $\gamma$ to $y$, and then through $\sigma$ to $z$. The idea is that if you have these two paths $\gamma,\sigma$, then you use the first half of the unit interval $[0,1/2]$ to cover the path $\gamma$ and the second half $[1/2,1]$ to cover the path $\sigma$

Comment: So sum of path is more like union?